# ios JSON parsing error Error Domain = NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 when uploading file and expecting response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

**UPDATED see end of post**

I am building my first iOS app, and I have created many functions where the app connects to a server and fetches data. In the functions where the app just sends data I set the server to reply with the following JSON response if everything is alright:

```
$reply = array('thisReply'=>'SUCCESS');
echo CJSON::encode($reply);
```

I tried this in the other functions of my app which send data to the server and it works like a charm. Here is the code I use to make the request:

(stringUrl is just my server string)

```
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:stringUrl];
    NSString *postMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&requestedDataEntry=%@", currentUser.username, password, requestedData];
    //turn post string into data object
    NSData *postData = [requestPostMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    //post data legnth
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    //url request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    //set up request properties
    [request setURL:requestURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


     //error attribute
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    //create response
    NSURLResponse *response;

    //json data
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    //pass symptom history objects into an array
    NSDictionary *jsonReponseData = (NSDictionary *) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

And I get the correct reply (the key/value pair 'thisReply'=>'SUCCESS')

Here is my function to upload a file (and send my post data) which I copied from a reply here on stackoverflow:

```
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:stringUrl];

//get curent user username and password
User *currentUser = [[User alloc]initWithSavedUser];
NSString *password = passWordString; //(not actual code)

//get also send as sms string
NSString *sendSMS = [[NSString alloc] init];
if(smsBoolean)
{
    sendSMS = @"YES";
}
else
{
    sendSMS = @"NO";
}
//get file attached string
NSString *recordedMessageExists = [[NSString alloc] init];
if(recordedMessageBoolean)
{
    recordedMessageExists = @"YES";
}
else
{
    recordedMessageExists = @"NO";
}

NSDictionary *params = @{@"username" : currentUser.username,
                         @"password" : password,
                         @"patientID" : patientID,
                         @"sendSMS" : sendSMS,
                         @"message" : message,
                         @"attachFile" : recordedMessageExists};

//get an array with the files path
NSArray *pathsArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//copy documents path into an nstring
NSString *documentsPath = [pathsArray objectAtIndex:0];
//get path for recorded message
NSString *soundFilePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameString];

//create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Boundary-%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//set request http method and url
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:url];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

// Append parameters data into post url
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *parameterKey, NSString *parameterValue, BOOL *stop) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", parameterKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", parameterValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}];

// attach file if user has added one
if(recordedMessageBoolean)
{
    //get filename
    NSString *filename  = [soundFilePath lastPathComponent];
    NSData   *data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
    NSString *mimetype  = [self mimeTypeForPath:soundFilePath];
    //append file to post body
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"messageFile", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", mimetype] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:data];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//set request's body
[request setHTTPBody:body];
//post data legnth
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
// create url response
NSURLResponse *response;
//set up NSerror
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

//-- Getting response form server
//send update to server
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

//pass reply into an NSDictionary
NSDictionary *jsonReponseData = (NSDictionary *) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

And the mimeTypeForPath function

```
- (NSString *)mimeTypeForPath:(NSString *)path
{
// get a mime type for an extension using MobileCoreServices.framework

CFStringRef extension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[path pathExtension];
CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, extension, NULL);


NSString *mimetype = CFBridgingRelease(UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType));


CFRelease(UTI);

return mimetype;
}
```

The post data along with the sound file get sent to the server correctly, and the server performs all of its functions, but when it returns the json reply, responseData is set, but the NSDictionary jsonResponseData is nil and I get an error report saying:

```
JSON parsing error Error Domain = NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
```

And

```
NSDebugDescription @"JSON text did not begin with an array or object....".
```

I googled those errors online and all the results said that this error comes up when there's something wrong with the JSON string, BUT the same exact json string works in the first function, so I think it must be something I am doing wrong with the request, but I got all that code from all over the place and it's hard to tell what's causing the error. Can someone help me please?

**UPDATED**

I logged the response data and it turns out I got the entire web page as a JSON response, which is what's causing the problem.

**UPDATE 2 and Final Answer**

I found the error. I had code which copied the sent file unto the server temporarily, before it attached it on an email and sent it out (and finally deleted the file).But I had this outside of an if check to check if a file to be attached was even posted by the app. After I put an if check this error stopped happening on either scenario (with or withOUT a file attached).

Comment: By the way, when you get the immediate problem behind you, I'd suggest you excise your code of the `sendSynchronousRequest`. You never want to issue synchronous requests from the main queue.

Comment: I will google tutorials on this once I am done, thanks

Comment: Also note that in your original `x-www-form-urlencoded` request, you are not percent encoding the parameters. If, for example, the password had a `&` or `+` in it, this code wouldn't work. Always percent-encode your `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests (but not your `multipart/form-data` requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should examine the contents of `responseData`, e.g.,

```
NSLog(@"responseData = %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

I suspect that you'll see that it doesn't conform to valid JSON. Edit your question showing us what it says.

You might want to log the `response` object and make sure the `statusCode` is 200 as well. If not 200, then you have some server related problem.

By the way, your JSON parsing routine doesn't use the `error` parameter. Whenever you have problems in your code, make sure you are availing yourself of all of the available error logging.

Comment: Yes you are RIGHT.....I get the ENTIRE webpage as a JSON response :S. I have no idea why though

Comment: It's usually a HTML page reporting an error arising from either either (a) a bug in the server's PHP code; (b) the server was looking for something in the request that was not provided correctly, but the server code did not handle the error gracefully; or (c) some simple error in the request (e.g. bad URL that returns a HTML page informing you of the 404 server code). That's why I suggest looking at the `statusCode` in the `response` object, as that can sometimes help you programmatically diagnose the source of the issue.

Comment: I found the error. I had code which copied the sent file unto the server temporarily, before it attached it on an email and sent it out (and finally deleted the file). But I had this outside of an if check to check if a file to be attached was even posted by the app. After I put an if check this error stopped happening on either scenario (with or withOUT a file attached).     Thanks a lot Rob :).